# Parallel within parallel

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

Lets say I have `n` tasks that I would like to run in paralel using `foreach` package. i-th task is defined by `f(dataset_i)` where `f` is function that requires time to complete depending of the size of `dataset_i`.

Function `f` itself can be parallelized, so I would like to allocate `cpu_i` to i-th task, and run `f(dataset_i)` with `cpu_i` cpus.

Is something like this possible, and if, how to do it?

Comment: It's possible but ineffective. The inner loop will get most or all processors assigned to the job and there will be very few, if any, processors available to the outer loop. As a rule of thumb, parallelize the inner loop.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Why is that? I tend to parallelize the outer loop if needed. Usually, I'd say, it is more efficient to have few long-running tasks than many short-running tasks.

Comment: I'm confused ... *"allocate `cpi_u` to i-th task"* suggests to me that the i-th task gets a single cpu, so how then do you *"run `f(dataset_i)`"* with more than the one cpu allocated to it? Sorry if I'm being dim.

Comment: @r2evans I meant to allocate number of cpus to each task - `cpu_i` is number of cpus allocated for i-th task.

Comment: @RuidBarradas When parallelizing inner loop is it possible to allocate more than 1 cpu per task. I ask because there can be big difference between datasets sizes.

Comment: The `future` package supports the notion of [nested futures and topologies](https://future.futureverse.org/#nested-futures-and-evaluation-topologies), which should (I believe) support what you're looking for. Add to that the [`doFuture`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doFuture/) package which extends `future` to support the `foreach` framework, I think that sounds like a reasonable attempt.

Comment: @Roland Ok, I generalized too much. It depends on how much time each task will take, to be a inner loop task doesn't mean it will be short. Nor that those should be ones parallelized.

Answer (score 0):

R level parallelisim is always process parallelism. Tasks are not sent to
different CPU cores, but rather separate R sessions running on different
threads. Importantly however, all the R sessions still have access to all
cores. So if you have a function `f()` that can perform a task on multiple
threads (= separate cores) by calling to native code, you should specify
when launching the task how many threads `f()` should use.

Concretely, with `f = data.table::fwrite`:

```r
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
#> Loading required package: iterators
#> Loading required package: parallel

registerDoParallel()

datasets <- list(
  data.frame(foo = rnorm(1e7)),
  data.frame(foo = rnorm(2e7))
)

foreach(data = datasets, ncpu = c(1, 2)) %dopar% {
  file <- withr::local_tempfile()
  data.table::fwrite(data, file, nThread = ncpu) |> system.time()
}
#> [[1]]
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.72    0.06    0.85 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    1.31    0.14    0.78

stopImplicitCluster()
```